# Handling State Updates for Cancelled Axios Requests with AbortController in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, react-redux

I've integrated AbortController into my React application to cancel Axios requests as part of my state management with Redux. My setup includes dispatching actions to update the application state when initiating and completing requests.

The issue arises when a request is cancelled using AbortController. Currently, if a request is cancelled, my application's state may incorrectly remain in an isFetching: true state or it or worse, set an error state hasError: true, even though the request was intentionally cancelled and not actually in error or still fetching. ( this is because sometimes the cancellation is registered as an error and an error action is dispatched)

How can I efficiently manage my Redux state for cancelled requests to accurately reflect the state of the UI and not leave parts of my application in a perpetual loading or erroneous state due to cancelled operations?

AND another main question - is updating the state even needed in my case? The user has aborted the call, but the state is on another page